# How do I merge two different collections of same database into a new collection having similar field values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

I have a collection called "datas" and the other collection is named as "aidretentionandgraduations" in a database called "challenge". Both collections have similar values stored in different field called unitId and Unitid, their values should be used to merge those two collections. So if **unitId==elevatorInfo.Institution_Characteristics.Unitid** display the documents else don't dispaly.
below is what I tried:

```
  db.aidretentionandgraduations([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'datas', 
      'localField': 'Unitid', 
      'foreignField': 'unitId', 
      'as': 'nice'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$nice'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
          '$unitId', '$elevatorInfo.Institution_Characteristics.Unitid'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

data collection:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "627f925ffa5e617f51d5632e"  },  "elevatorInfo": {    "Institution_Characteristics": {      "Unitid": "139384",      "Name": "Georgia Northwestern Technical College",      "City": "Rome",      "State": "GA",      "Web_Address": "www.gntc.edu/",      "Distance_Learning": "Offers undergraduate courses and/or programs"    }  },  "studentCharges": {    "Cost": {      "Published_Tuition_And_Required_Fees": "",      "In-state": "$3,062",      "Out-of-state": "$5,462",      "Books_And_Supplies": "$1,500",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family)_Room_And_Board": "$5,528",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family)_Other_Expenses": "$5,191",      "Off-campus_(with_Family)_Other_Expenses": "$2,431",      "Total_Cost": "",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family),_In-state": "$15,281",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family),_Out_Of_State": "$17,681",      "Off-campus_(with_Family),_In-state": "$6,993",      "Off-campus_(with_Family),_Out-of-state": "$9,393"    },    "Level_of_student": {      "Undergraduate": {        "In-state": "$3,062",        "Out-of-state": "$5,462"      },      "Graduate": {        "In-state": "",        "Out-of-state": ""      }    }  }}
```

aidretentionandgraduations collection:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "622ce9ba5d72be4d703e972d"  },  "financialAid": {    "Student_Financial_Aid": {      "All_Undergraduate_Students": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": ""      },      "Any_Grant_Or_Scholarship_Aid": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "90%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$5,603"      },      "Pell_Grants": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "69%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$7,845"      },      "Federal_Student_Loans": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "8%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$3,371"      },      "Full-time,_First-time,_Degree/certificate-seeking_Undergraduate_Students": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": ""      }    }  },  "retentionAndGraduation": {    "Retention_And_Graduation": {      "Overall_Graduation_Rates": {        "Rate": " "      },      "Total": {        "Rate": "49%"      },      "Men": {        "Rate": "57%"      },      "Women": {        "Rate": "40%"      },      "Nonresident_Alien": {        "Rate": "100%"      },      "Transfer_Out-rate": {        "Rate": "7%"      }    }  },  "unitId": 139384,  "__v": 0}
```

Final output stored as uni:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "622fffe6b9ccae37d3bd3b92"  },  "financialAid": {    "Student_Financial_Aid": {      "All_Undergraduate_Students": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": ""      },      "Any_Grant_Or_Scholarship_Aid": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "90%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$5,603"      },      "Pell_Grants": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "69%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$7,845"      },      "Federal_Student_Loans": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "8%",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": "$3,371"      },      "Full-time,_First-time,_Degree/certificate-seeking_Undergraduate_Students": {        "Percent_receiving_aid": "",        "Average_amount_of_aid_received": ""      }    }  },  "retentionAndGraduation": {    "Retention_And_Graduation": {      "Overall_Graduation_Rates": {        "Rate": " "      },      "Total": {        "Rate": "49%"      },      "Men": {        "Rate": "57%"      },      "Women": {        "Rate": "40%"      },      "Nonresident_Alien": {        "Rate": "100%"      },      "Transfer_Out-rate": {        "Rate": "7%"      }    }  },  "unitId": 139384,  "studentCharges": {    "Cost": {      "Published_Tuition_And_Required_Fees": "",      "In-state": "$3,062",      "Out-of-state": "$5,462",      "Books_And_Supplies": "$1,500",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family)_Room_And_Board": "$5,528",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family)_Other_Expenses": "$5,191",      "Off-campus_(with_Family)_Other_Expenses": "$2,431",      "Total_Cost": "",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family),_In-state": "$15,281",      "Off-campus_(not_With_Family),_Out_Of_State": "$17,681",      "Off-campus_(with_Family),_In-state": "$6,993",      "Off-campus_(with_Family),_Out-of-state": "$9,393"    },    "Level_of_student": {      "Undergraduate": {        "In-state": "$3,062",        "Out-of-state": "$5,462"      },      "Graduate": {        "In-state": "",        "Out-of-state": ""      }    }  },  "elevatorInfo": {    "Institution_Characteristics": {      "Unitid": "139384",      "Name": "Georgia Northwestern Technical College",      "City": "Rome",      "State": "GA",      "Web_Address": "www.gntc.edu/",      "Distance_Learning": "Offers undergraduate courses and/or programs"    }  },  "__v": 0}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real problem was type casting. I failed to  notice that unitId was a number(int32) but Unitid was a string, because of this aggregation operation was not carried out. Mongodb community forum  helped me to realize such a trivial mistake. Here is the [link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-do-i-merge-two-different-collections-of-same-database-into-a-new-collection-having-similar-field-values-in-mongodb-compass/163912) to that. The code with type conversion is as follows:

```
    [
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'unitId': {
        '$toString': '$unitId'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'datas', 
      'localField': 'unitId', 
      'foreignField': 'elevatorInfo.Institution_Characteristics.Unitid', 
      'as': 'nice'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$nice'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '__v': 0, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $[out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) or $[merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) aggregate stages. I didn't exactly understand what is your problem with $merge since you didn't provide your code, but if you need modify output of $lookup, you can do it via $[project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) before $out or $merge.

Comment: my apologies ,I am actually using mongodb compass and that is why the code may not be recognizable at first glance. to be precise I am facing  problem trying to compare and replace unitID field of aidretentiongraduations which is not equal to Unitid of datas collection.   '$eq': [
          '$unitId', '$elevatorInfo.Institution_Characteristics.Unitid'
        ] ... i want to  allow only unitId== Unitid documents to exists.